# USB not mounting in UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: usb, mount

Neither my pen-drives nor my wireless mouse are getting mounted or connected. During startup it shows something about `USB 3-7 not accepting address` or similar. I checked in DISKS and my pen-drive doesn't show up.

Result of `lsusb` with plugged-in pen-drive:

```
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post and provide the output of `lsusb` (use code formatting **`{}`**)?

Comment: i did as you told me to

Comment: Was this the output with the pendrive plugged in or not? Sorry that I forgot to mention that earlier, but please add both.

Comment: pendrive plugged in.

Comment: Can you give the details about your motherboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked. 
I did a

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
    sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

then rebooted the system and everything seems to be working properly

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

according to this [LINK](http://choorucode.com/2014/05/06/the-strange-case-of-the-usb-error-device-not-accepting-address/) this is a kind of hardware error due to high temperature . can you try the solution to shutdown the PC and leave it till it cools up and tr again

Comment: tried.  still not working.